# Magento2 - How to add remove all wishlist button on the wishlish page?

Tags: magento2, wishlist

on the wishlist's page we have remove wishlist's button for each item, and we want to add a button that can remove all wish-list item all at once

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create my own module with a specific route to solve this problem, and I am thinking another best way to extend the action like do it from a plugin or something else, here are the code

```
<?php
namespace XXX\RemoveAllWishList\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\AbstractIndex
{
    /**
     * @var WishlistProviderInterface
     */
    protected $wishlistProvider;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider,
        Validator $formKeyValidator
    ) {
        $this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Remove item
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

        $wishlistId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('item');

        if (!$wishlistId) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }

        if($wishlistId) {
            $wishlist = $this->wishlistProvider->getWishlist($wishlistId);

            $wishlistCollection = $wishlist->getItemCollection();
            foreach ($wishlistCollection as $item) {
                $item->delete();
            }
            $wishlist->save();
        }
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $refererUrl = (string)$request->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
        $url = (string)$request->getParam(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL);
        if ($url) {
            $refererUrl = $url;
        }
        if ($request->getParam(\Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED) && $refererUrl) {
            $redirectUrl = $refererUrl;
        } else {
            $redirectUrl = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($this->_url->getUrl('*/*'));
        }
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectUrl);
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Here is the main method to delete all the wishlist item

```
foreach ($wishlistCollection as $item) {
     $item->delete();
}
$wishlist->save();
```

Thank You.